# SQL Server sp_describe_first_result_set: find user defined types

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-type

I need to find the column definitions from a stored procedure.The docs for [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) show an entry for `user_type_name` where I'd expect to see my [User Defined Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql). Sadly, data for UDTs seems to be missing from the procedure result. Given the sample code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @test TABLE (
        a BIGINT
        ,b udtTest
        ,c NVARCHAR(100)
        ,d BIT
    )

    INSERT INTO @test (
        a, b, c, d
    ) VALUES (
        1, 'udtTest', 'nvarchar', 0
    )

    select *
    from @test
END
GO
EXEC [dbo].[sp_describe_first_result_set] @tsql = N'test';
GO
```

I'm seeing the following ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4b430e30f41062232ff05d1780c69a0e)):

| name | system_type_name | user_type_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | bigint | *NULL* |
| b | nvarchar(123) | *NULL* |
| c | nvarchar(100) | *NULL* |
| d | bit | *NULL* |

Why is `udtTest` missing from my data for column name `b`?

Comment: FWIW, I can repro with the table variable like your example but it works as expected with a permanent table. Maybe someone can explain why.

Comment: Interesting question. Consider the differences between table variables, temp tables, and permanent tables (see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38835d50cf39fabaa5ea0cdf14829766). Would you care to edit some of that detail into your question (or would you mind if I take the liberty of doing so)? Note also the availability of [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) for a narrower result set while rubber-ducking

Comment: @PeterVandivier feel free to improve up my question

Answer (score 4):

This appears not to work as advertised. Temporary tables are disallowed, but table variables should work just fine. Alias types are a bit of an edge case, so perhaps a bug crept in here unnoticed. If it is a blocker for you, open a support case with Microsoft.

There aren't any perfect workarounds (that I am aware of). One of the best ones is to create a wrapper procedure that uses `WITH RESULT SETS` to define the output shape:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.udtTest FROM nvarchar(123) NOT NULL;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.P AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @T TABLE (udt dbo.udtTest);
INSERT @T VALUES (N'Banana');
SELECT T.udt FROM @T AS T;
GO
-- No user type info
EXECUTE sys.sp_describe_first_result_set 
    @tsql = N'EXECUTE Sandpit.dbo.P;', 
    @parameters = NULL, 
    @browse_information_mode = 0;
```

```
-- Wrapper for dbo.P
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.P_Wrapper AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
EXECUTE dbo.P 
    WITH RESULT SETS ((udt dbo.udtTest NOT NULL));
GO
-- Works!
EXECUTE sys.sp_describe_first_result_set 
    @tsql = N'EXECUTE dbo.P_Wrapper;', 
    @parameters = NULL, 
    @browse_information_mode = 0;
```

This may or may not be convenient or practical for you. It's probably the best we can do until the bug (?) is fixed, or Microsoft [extend](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32910508-stored-procedures-should-expose-detailed-contracts) `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax to include `WITH RESULT SETS`, as we have been asking for a long time now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is indeed not a practical solution in my case. I'll keep on digging and consider your solution as last chance.